# How to enable top and bottom margins between a series of spans inside a div?

Tags: css

I have a div containing a number of spans. Each span has padding and background-color to separate it from the others. The problem is that when the spans overflow into the next line, the paddings of spans on different lines overlap. I have tried assigning top and bottom margins to the spans, but they are ignored. How do I apply a spacing between the spans?

html:

```
<div class='container-div'>
  <span class='item'>foo</span>
  <span class='item'>blah blah</span>
  <span class='item'>abracadabra</span>
  <span class='item'>bar</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.item {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Suppose the div shows the first two spans on the first line, and then naturally wraps to show the latter two spans in the second line. The gray padding of the two lines overlap. The margin-top and margin-bottom are ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand right you are wonder why inline elements ignore margin:

> **8.3 Margin properties: 'margin-top', 'margin-right', 'margin-bottom', 'margin-left', and 'margin'**
>
> Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The
>   'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while
>   the other margin properties only set their respective side. These
>   properties apply to all elements, but vertical margins will not have
>   any effect on non-replaced inline elements.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties

So you can simulate the behavior you want using `inline-block`:

```css
.container-div {
  width: 50px;
}
.item {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-div'>
  <span class='item'>foo</span>
  <span class='item'>blah blah</span>
  <span class='item'>abracadabra</span>
  <span class='item'>bar</span>
</div>
```

**References**

[Replaced Elements](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements)

Comment: @Anand Glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a div containing a number of spans. Each span has `padding` and `background-color` to separate it from the others.

`padding` doesn't separate an element from another. And `background-color` may distinguish each `span` by varying backgrounds, but it doesn't separate it either. `margin` is used to separate elements.

However, spans, in accordance with the CSS box model for inline elements [won't recognize vertical margin](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/).

> How do I apply a spacing between the spans?

One solution involves using `inline-block`, as has been mentioned already by @AlexChar.

Another simple solution is to use a [**CSS Flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

HTML

```
<div class='container-div'>
     <span class='item'>foo</span>
     <span class='item'>blah blah</span>
     <span class='item'>abracadabra</span>
     <span class='item'>bar</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-div {
    display: flex;   
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

.item {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    margin: 10px;
    }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ec0tdag7/1/

Comment: Flex looks good too - what are the pros and cons of flex vs inline-block? I understand margin vs padding - by separation, I meant the visual separation of one span from another using padding+background-color.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. Flexbox is a clean, simple and efficient solution for layouts. You can position and center things easily and with minimal code. Sometimes, however, `inline-block` may be sufficient and no flexbox would be necessary. Like I said, depends on situation.